# Is there a way to tell which *coin is most profitable to mine?

Tags: namecoin, currencies, litecoin, peercoin

Basically a program that could run some hashes for all of the different hash functions that are used in the different big cryptocurrencies and then get the current difficulty from all of them. From there you can determine how many of those coins you could be mining and look up an exchange rate from there.

I was guessing that I should switch my GPU mining from bitcoins to litecoins, but I was just wondering if its worth it.

I was thinking about starting to write a small script to do this automatically if nothing like it exists.

Comment: I am usually against scam-like-currencies like these, but I found this question interesting so I gave an answer anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This site allows you to compare the mining profitability of the various coins: 
http://dustcoin.com/mining

Comment: Awesome! thanks for that. Never even heard of novacoin.

Answer (score 2):

Despite being an interesting and fun problem, it will be likely pointless, due to arbitrage.

Since there is at least an open exchange supporting each currency, and since we can safely assume there is at least one single bot or person exploiting arbitrage, you will most likely get the same value for every currency.

Comment: Well that has to do with the current exchange rate between the currencies, that doesn't specifically say how hard it is to *mine* those currencies. Also if someone is doing arbitrage without a tool like this its entirely possible you could do it better than them.

Answer (score -1):

you can try  [bestcoin.udf.me](http://bestcoin.udf.me) it is a new site with calculator, and charts